# Given a Pell solution $(u_k,v_k)$, is there a closed form "descent" to $(u_{k-1},v_{k-1})$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Given: a solution $(u_k,v_k)$ to the Pell equation
$$U^2-dV^2=1, \qquad(\star)$$
where $d$ is a non-square integer, and $k \ge 1$ is an arbitrary integer.

There are well-known recurrences to *ascend* to $(u_{k+1}, v_{k+1})$, given also the fundamental solution $(u_1,v_1)$. I'm wondering if there's a closed form “reverse recurrence” which gives $(u_{k-1},v_{k-1})$, without knowing $(u_1,v_1)$ explicitly.

As a concrete numerical example, when $d=2$, we can compute $v_{k-1} = u_k-v_k$, and then compute $u_{k-1}=v_k-v_{k-1}$, which gives a solution to the negative version of $(\star)$; applied twice, you get back to the next smaller solution for the positive version. It's this kind of “descent”, in a general case, that I'm interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. Knowledge of how to perform your descent is equivalent to knowledge of the fundamental solution. Given $d > 0$ not a square, the previous solution is given by multiplying the column vector by
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
s & -d t \\
-t & s
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where $$ s^2 - d t^2 = 1  $$
is the fundamental solution.
Given $(x,y)$ that solves $x^2 - d y^2 = 1,$ the previous solution is
$$ (s x - d t y, \; \;  -t x + s y); $$ but the next solution is
$$ (s x + d t y, \; \;  t x + s y); $$

Meanwhile, the matrix (either) has trace $2s$ and determinant $1.$ If you know two consecutive solutions, Cayley-Hamilton says 
$$ x_{n+2} = 2 \, s \;  x_{n+1} - x_n,  $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 2 \, s \; y_{n+1} - y_n.  $$
Once again, knowledge of $2s$ tells you the fundamental solution.

Answer (score -1):

If we have any solution of the equation Pell: $$x^2-dy^2=1$$
   Having a form: $(x_1;y_1)$    The following solution we can always be obtained by the formula:  $$x_2=x_0x_1+dy_0y_1$$   $$y_2=y_0x_1+x_0y_1$$    This formula gives all solutions. In order to choose the direction of growth is necessary to change the sign of the substitution solution. Instead " $+$ " write " $-$ "

$(x_0;y_0)$ - the first solution of the Pell equation.

Comment: This requires knowledge of $(x_1,y_1)$ and/or $(x_0,y_0)$, and I specifically mentioned that we _don't_ have such knowledge.

Comment: As knowing nothing can solutions be found? $(x_0;y_0)$ - is easy and known.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... $(x_0,y_0)$ is _not_ known, if all I give you is $(u_k,v_k)$ for some unknown $k$.

Here's a concrete example with $d=2$: given the known solution $(u_k,v_k)=(99,70)$, we can compute the next smaller solution $(17,12)$ by computing $29=99-70$ and then $41=70-29$ to get $(41,29)$, and then repeating that procedure to get $(17,12)$. So if $d \ne 2$, what is the [general] procedure?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan (x_0;y_0)-(3;2)  $x=3*99-2*2*70=17$  ;  $y=2*99-3*70=-12$ If $d$ it is known, always known and $(x_0;y_0)$

Comment: That's exactly my point: in the general case $d$, we don't know $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan No need to fantasize. We can always find these numbers.

Comment: Okay. Let $u_k,v_k$ be integers, and $d$ be a non-square integer, such that $u_k^2-dv_k^2=1$. Please give me the formula for the next smaller solution $(u_{k-1},v_{k-1})$ in terms of only $d$, $u_k$, and $v_k$, as I did with the example $d=2$.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan  $d$ -  cannot be a square. I already showed.