# Can the fundamental solution of a Pell equation be “triangulated” given multiple known solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

In [this question about “descent” given a single Pell solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901119/given-a-pell-solution-u-k-v-k-is-there-a-closed-form-descent-to-u-k-1), Will Jagy gave the [accepted] answer that, for a Pell equation
$$
  U^2 - dV^2 = \pm 1,  \tag{$\star$}
$$
there is no way to determine the fundamental solution $(u_1,v_1)$ — or even the next smaller solution $(u_{k-1},v_{k-1})$ — given only a single solution $(u_k,v_k)$ for [unknown] integer $k \ge 1$.

My followup question is this:

Would it be possible to determine the fundamental solution of ($\star$) given $m \ge 2$ solutions $(u_{k_1},v_{k_1}) \le (u_{k_2},v_{k_2}) \le \dots \le (u_{k_m},v_{k_m})$, without knowing exactly *which* solutions these were (*e.g.*, in particular, it cannot be assumed that they are adjacent solutions)? If so, is there a minimum $m$ for which such a method/algorithm would always work?

For example, given only the three [ordered] solutions
$$(7,5),\quad(1393,985),\quad(9369319, 6625109),$$
could one determine that $(u_1,v_1)=(1,1)$?

EDIT: As individ pointed out, the numerical example is trivial to calculate from. I'm actually thinking about more general equations with variables involved, *e.g.*, given the three ordered, but not necessarily consecutive, solutions
$$(u_{k_1},v_{k_1}),\quad (u_{k_2},v_{k_2}),\quad (u_{k_3},v_{k_3}),$$
is there an algebraic method to determine $(u_1,v_1)$ as an algebraic identity in terms of [one or more of] the variables $u_{k_1},v_{k_1},u_{k_2},v_{k_2},u_{k_3},v_{k_3}$, or a way to calculate $d$ as an integer explicitly (say, given some divisibility properties or factors of the variables)?

Comment: I don't understand. It's hard to calculate? $d=\frac{U^2\pm1}{V^2}$

Comment: @individ Good point. See edits.

Comment: @individ: Since $d$ can be calculated that way using each of the given solutions, there may be a way to use that information alone to derive a contradiction in some cases. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I think the problem must be reformulated. There is a Pell equation:    $p^2-ds^2=1$  As the ratio? $d$ we find the first solution to this equation.  As this is done I have shown in the previous topic.  For some factors there is a simple formula, without the use of continued fractions.

Comment: You may be interested in this: Jeans, N. S., and Hendy M. D. "Determining the Fundamental Unit of a Pure Cubic Field Given Any Unit." Mathematics of Computation 32, no. 143 (1978): 925-35.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is poorly phrased, but if you represent the solutions as $u+v\sqrt{d}$, where $u^2-dv^2 = \pm 1$, then every solution (in positive integers) is a power of the fundamental solution.

So, different question: given a bunch of powers $z^a, z^b, z^c,\ldots$, can I determine $z$?  Not necessarily!  I might have been unlucky and all of $a,b,c$ are even.  Then I can never directly construct any non-even powers.  Same with multiples of $3$, and so on.

On the other hand, if I have just two solutions where the powers are relatively prime, then I can find the primitive solution using the Euclidean algorithm.

For example, if I'm given $a=7+5\sqrt{2}$ and $b=1393 + 985\sqrt{2}$, I can compute $a/b = 99+70\sqrt{2}$, $a/b^2 = 7+5\sqrt{2}$... and uh-oh, it looks like my two solutions were both third powers, and $7+5\sqrt{2}$ is as low as I can go.  But if I throw $c= 9369319 + 6625109\sqrt{2}$ into the mix, I can find the fundamental solution, e.g. $c/b^2 = 1+\sqrt{2}$.

EDIT (Kieren): See comments for details on using the g.c.d. of the powers.

Comment: It was known 2000 years ago. The question is. Is there a formula which would allow to find solutions to this equation are directly at odds.

Comment: Excellent! (And apologies for the poor phrasing.) So is $3$ the minimum number of solutions to always be able to find the fundamental solution, or does it still depend on whether the solutions (or powers) have a common factor?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan It has nothing to do with the number of solutions, and everything to do with the greatest common divisor.

Comment: GCD of the _solutions_, or of the _exponents_, _i.e._, $\gcd(k_1,k_2)$?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan The solutions you gave were $(1+\sqrt{2})^3$, $(1+\sqrt{2})^9$, $(1+\sqrt{2})^{19}$.  The first two don't work, because $(3,9) = 3$, but the third one works with either of the first two.

Comment: So I think you're saying $m=2$ if any of the $\gcd(k_i,k_j)=1$, and $m=\infty$ otherwise? If so, please edit your answer, and I'll accept it soon. But if there's some other way of using additional solutions _even with $\gcd(k_i,k_j)>1$_ to help, please comment on that as well. Thanks!

Comment: @KierenMacMillan You could have the solutions $z^6, z^{10}, z^{15}$.  Then any two solutions are inadequate, but all three can give you $z$.  This is identical to the problem of computing gcds of natural numbers, where in principal I could have a million integers, each one divisible by all but one of a set of a million primes.  Then I need every last one to hash out the gcd.

Comment: The point is that the smallest solution generated by a set $\{z^{k_i}\}$ is exactly $z^{\gcd(k_1, k_2, \ldots)}$.